# Can I rename setup.txt to setup.ts (and constants) in my TYPO3 Extensions?

Tags: typo3

In an Extension of TYPO3 I want to rename setup.txt to setup.ts and constants.txt to constants.ts.

What stand for Pro and what for Contra to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can rename these files since the `.ts` file extension is [supported since TYPO3v7](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/7.4/Feature-34922-AllowTsFileExtensionForStaticTyposcriptTemplates.html).

The benefits depend on your development environment. If you have a plugin which adds syntax highlighting not only based on the file type (e.g. [ApplySyntax](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ApplySyntax) for Sublime), not much will change. If not, then you can at least tell your environment to treat `.ts` files as TypoScript.

However, `.ts` is also not the best option yet since this file extension is already used by quite a few other file types (TypeScript, MPEG-2 transport streams).

That's why you can also use `.typoscript` [starting with TYPO3v8](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.7.x/Feature-78161-IntroduceTypoScriptFileExtension.html). In the long term every TypoScript file will use this file extension so **using .typoscript for TYPO3 version 8 and above is strongly recommended**.

Comment: I develope on TYPO3 8 only and soon 9, so the best way, if I understood coorect, is not txt not ts but .typoscript. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the recommended way now. Makes your life with your IDE easier - no reconfiguration of assigned file types needed...

Answer (score 2):

As long as you implement the folder, where the typoscript is located, this shouldn't be a problem.

In ../Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php:

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile('myExt', 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'My Extension TS');

Comment: Yes, that I alway do if I create a new Extension via ExtBuilder. Move this from **ext_tables.php** to **Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php**. But thanks anyway ;).